# Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I get the following error when I try to save Parse objectId as a Pointer value for the User class: `Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.`

I have a UICollectionView that shows a list of avatars (Avatar class in Parse). When a user selects an avatar in the list, I want to set that User's avatar to the selected image using a Pointer value.

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(self.avatars[indexPath.row])

        self.user["avatar"] = self.avatars[indexPath.row]["objectId"]

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnToProfile", sender: user)
    }

}
```

User has Pointer column to the Avatar class. Trying to get the Avatar objectId to place into the column in the User table but I keep getting the error. What's odd is that `print(self.avatars[indexPath.row])` returns the following:

```
<Avatar: 0x7f8ebb835c80, objectId: WG7L0KpdJ2, localId: (null)> {
    file = "<PFFile: 0x7f8ebb837dc0>";
    name = man;
}
```

objectId exists, but if I try to print with `print(self.avatars[indexPath.row]["objectId")` I get nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Updated code:

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()

user!["avatar"] = self.avatars[indexPath.row].objectId

do {
   print(self.avatars[indexPath.row].objectId)
   try user?.save()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

the print statement prints the correct objectId. However, saving it to the user causes error `invalid type for key avatar, expected *Avatar, but got string" UserInfo={code=111, temporary=0, error`

**EDIT 2: Pointers don't save the objectId.** You have to save the ENTIRE OBJECT. Just figured this out. Here's the updated code that now works. Thanks for the help everyone!!

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.user["avatar"] = self.avatars[indexPath.row]

        do {
           try self.user.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnToProfile", sender: user)
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get 'objectId' as one of the values if you send `-allKeys` to the avatar object?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would I go about doing that? `print(self.avatars.allKeys)` doesn't work

Comment: It's a property on `PFObject` so you need to call it in on the object not the array (see [docs here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(py)objectId)) - but now I read the docs more closely, it seems it never returns `objectId` anyway. Happily there is an `objectId` property as well - try that `let avatar = self.avatars[indexPath.row]` then `avatar.objectId`

Comment: Thanks! That helped but I get an error when I save the User. Updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the ID: `self.user["avatar"] = self.avatars[indexPath.row].objectId`

In this case, `objectId` is a property of the object, not one of it's dictionary subscripted values.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting close. `self.avatars[indexPath.row].objectId` does seem to print the correct id. However, when I try to print it or save it to the user, I get a weird error `invalid type for key avatar, expected *Avatar, but got string" UserInfo={code=111, temporary=0, error=`

Comment: Actually, the print statement seems to print the correct objectId. The problem is when I try to finally save that objectId to the avatar pointer column in User.

Comment: NVM, you have to save the whole object, not just objectId